# Sending Email from server PHP

Tags: php, sendmail, forms, http-post

I have a form in html file and I'm trying to get email on my gmail account when user fill the form and submit it. My website is running on Server not on local host.My code has no error but still not getting the email .I dont know why? Can any one give me sample code or tell  me what am I doing wrong? .. Thanks in advance ...
Here is my Code

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the sendemail.php is

```
<?php 
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'khurram.ansar@gmail.com';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));`

Comment: Does mail work?

Try

`mail('khurram.ansar@gmail.com','test','test');` – [Brucie Alpha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5380431/brucie-alpha)

Comment: You are connected to a mail server right? What is the host you are using?

Comment: The [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function expects `$headers` to be a string, not an array.

Comment: Please check you SPAM folder for the mail, after correcting headers. Because gmail put mails from unknown servers to spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) :

> Multiple extra headers should be separated **with a CRLF (\r\n)**.

So your php file should be like :

```
<?php
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$from = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$to = 'khurram.ansar@gmail.com';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
        "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n" .
        "From: {$name} <{$from}>" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: <{$from}>" . "\r\n" .
        "Subject: {$subject}" . "\r\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
?>
```